# Using pre_get_posts to set posts per page, how do I?

Tags: taxonomy, pre-get-posts

I am trying to use pre_get_posts to set posts per page for a single term within a taxonomy. One thing that is throwing me off is setting the term to apply the pre_get_posts to.

Here's my code:

```
function filter_press_tax( $query ){
if( $query->query_vars['tax_query']['taxonomy'] == 'press' && $query->query_vars['tax_query']['terms'][0] == 'press' ):
    $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 5;
    return;
endif;
}//end filter_press_tax
```

I'm not quite understanding how to access the taxonomy and term in the $query. Yes the taxonomy and term have the same name. Is this a bad idea? I do not have a custom query set up on the taxonomy-press-press.php template for the 'tax_query' is this the problem?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're almost there mate. Try this though.

```
<?php
    add_action('pre_get_posts', 'filter_press_tax');

    function filter_press_tax( $query ){
        if( $query->is_tax('press') && $query->has_term('press')):
            $query->set('posts_per_page', 5);
            return;
        endif;
    }
?>
```

You can use any [conditional tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) or any argument that can be passed to `WP_Query` to test your condition or set a new value via `pre_get_posts`. Also try `$query->get('taxonomy')` / `$query->get('term')`.
And check [this](http://www.billerickson.net/customize-the-wordpress-query/) for `$query`'s set and get methods.

Comment: Thanks for this! The is_tax works great but still cannot set the term. has_term throws an error and using get('term') doesn't apply the posts per page. Tried using get('term') == slug, id and name values but with no luck. Then tried $query->query_vars['term'] also with no luck. I must still be missing something. Looked into the $query stdClass Obj here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts and don't see a 'term' or has_term value in the list. It works as long as I don't try and set the term. Strange.

Comment: You're welcome! You want to set the term? Lemme take a look at it and see how it can be done.

Comment: Thanks! it works fine for the moment and my other term in the press taxonomy, called online reviews, isn't affected too terribly much. I look forward to anything you might find that could be helpful. :)

Comment: Welcome again! Actually I don't have a cpt/taxonomy setup at hand right now, hence couldn't test it. But sure will test as soon as I set the things and update here. :D